# Effect dispatched an invalid action - Actions must be objects

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-effects

When I add in `.map(...)` notification service and CLOSE dialog function I get errors.

What is the proper way to set this? 
Here is my effect

```
@Effect()
    addNewUser$ = this.actions$.pipe(
     ofType(actions.UserActionTypes.addNewUser),
        mergeMap((user: actions.addNewUser) =>
          this.userService.createUser(user.user).pipe(
             map(() => {
               new actions.LoadUsers(),
               this.notificationService.success("User added successfully!");  <--- added
               this.dialogRef.closeAll();    <--- added 
             }),
    catchError(error => of(new actions.Error(error.error)))
  )
)
```

);

I get error

> core.js:6014 ERROR Error: Effect "UserEffects.addNewUser$" dispatched an invalid action: undefined
>
> TypeError: Actions must be objects

Any help? Thnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the error says, you should be returning an action.
The `map` doesn't have a return value, so it will return `undefined` - causing the error.

Try the following:

```
this.notificationService.success("User added successfully!");  <--- added
this.dialogRef.closeAll();    <--- added
return new actions.LoadUsers();
```